# jQuery Counter Closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm trying to create a counter via a closure using javascript for all links clicked on a page.  This is what I have so far, but it is using a global variable.  How do I modify this, using a closed variable?

```
var count = 0;
$('body').on('click', '.a', function() {  
    count++;
    console.log(count)
})
```

Comment: What object has class .a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) around it:

```
(function(){ 
  var count = 0;
  $('body').on('click', '.a', function() {  
    count++;
    console.log(count)
  });
})();
```

Javascript has function scoping, so `count` will be local to that outer anonymous function.

Comment: That was easy.  Thanks!